# how to use XLOOKUP to copy row data to specific cells

Tags: excel-formula

### How to use XLOOKUP in excel to merge selected row data into specific cells?

how do copy the full elected data from 2 different sheets into the specific cells depending on criteria (i,e spreadsheet 1 cell 2  corresponds to spreadsheet 2 cell 2 and its associated row data) using Xlookup in the table below?

[image]

Tried playing about with xlookup but could not get the formula to work.

Comment: Just use TRANSPOSE: `=TRANSPOSE(Sheet2!A2:I2)`  It will spill the results

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your suggestion.  for this I am  looking to keep the row data as rows  when using xlookup (or a better alternative) so that the spreadsheet 2 data gets automatically  merged into the same  cell value in spreadsheet 1?

Comment: Why XLOOKUP if you have actual reference ?(in other words, you know the row, so no need looking it up). What do you mean by merge? Do you mean `=CONCAT(Sheet2!A2:I2)`